std::unordered_map<> の使い方が知りたい 「ペアが構築できない」みたいなエラーの対処方法
質問内容
以下のコードではSceneManagerクラスのヘッダファイルのプライベート変数のsceneList静的変数で以下のエラーが起きるのですが、エラーコードがヒントにならず、対処方法がわかりません。
環境
OS: Windows 10
terminal: msys2
言語バージョン：C++20
行いたい事
constを使ってキーと値の値を変更不可し、値が持つアドレスの指す先は変更できるようしたい。
現状のコード
非constでの実装を試していますが、提示のエラーコードが出ます。
知りたいこと

エラーコードの意味
"行いこと" を実装する方法

行ったこと、調べたこと

ChatGPT でエラーコードをコピペして回答を取得
SceneManager.hppで問題が起きていることをエラーコードの行数とファイル名を元に特定

エラーコード
長すぎる為、ヒントになる場所と思われる一部を抜粋
FAILED: CMakeFiles/game_project.dir/src/engine/SceneManager.cpp.obj
C:\terminal\mingw64\bin\g++.exe  -IC:/terminal/home/yw325/pixel/include -std=gnu++20 -MD -MT CMakeFiles/game_project.dir/src/engine/Sc
eneManager.cpp.obj -MF CMakeFiles\game_project.dir\src\engine\SceneManager.cpp.obj.d -o CMakeFiles/game_project.dir/src/engine/SceneMa
nager.cpp.obj -c C:/terminal/home/yw325/pixel/src/engine/SceneManager.cpp
In file included from C:/terminal/mingw64/include/c++/14.1.0/ext/alloc_traits.h:34,
                 from C:/terminal/mingw64/include/c++/14.1.0/bits/hashtable_policy.h:39,
                 from C:/terminal/mingw64/include/c++/14.1.0/bits/hashtable.h:35,
                 from C:/terminal/mingw64/include/c++/14.1.0/bits/unordered_map.h:33,
                 from C:/terminal/mingw64/include/c++/14.1.0/unordered_map:41,
                 from C:/terminal/home/yw325/pixel/include/engine/SceneManager.hpp:4,
                 from C:/terminal/home/yw325/pixel/src/engine/SceneManager.cpp:1:
C:/terminal/mingw64/include/c++/14.1.0/bits/alloc_traits.h: In instantiation of 'static constexpr void std::allocator_traits<std::allo
cator<_Up> >::construct(allocator_type&, _Up*, _Args&& ...) [with _Up = std::pair<const std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>, engine::Scen
e*>; _Args = {std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >, const engine::Scene*&}; _Tp = std::__de
tail::_Hash_node<std::pair<const std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>, engine::Scene*>, true>; allocator_type = std::allocator<std::__deta
il::_Hash_node<std::pair<const std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>, engine::Scene*>, true> >]':
C:/terminal/mingw64/include/c++/14.1.0/bits/hashtable_policy.h:2024:36:   required from 'std::__detail::_Hashtable_alloc<_NodeAlloc>::
__node_type* std::__detail::_Hashtable_alloc<_NodeAlloc>::_M_allocate_node(_Args&& ...) [with _Args = {std::__cxx11::basic_string<char
, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >, const engine::Scene*&}; _NodeAlloc = std::allocator<std::__detail::_Hash_node<std::p
air<const std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>, engine::Scene*>, true> >; __node_ptr = std::allocator<std::__detail::_Hash_node<std::pair<
const std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>, engine::Scene*>, true> >::value_type*]'
 2024 |             __node_alloc_traits::construct(__alloc, __n->_M_valptr(),
      |             ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
 2025 |                                            std::forward<_Args>(__args)...);
      |                                            ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

//////////////////////////
中略
//////////////////////////

C:/terminal/home/yw325/pixel/include/engine/SceneManager.hpp:19:30:   required from here
   19 |             sceneList.emplace(std::string(name),scene);
      |             ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
C:/terminal/mingw64/include/c++/14.1.0/bits/stl_pair.h:335:9: note: candidate: 'template<class ... _Args1, long long unsigned int ..._
Indexes1, class ... _Args2, long long unsigned int ..._Indexes2> constexpr std::pair<_T1, _T2>::pair(std::tuple<_Args1 ...>&, std::tup
le<_Args2 ...>&, std::_Index_tuple<_Indexes1 ...>, std::_Index_tuple<_Indexes2 ...>) [with _Args1 = {_Args1 ...}; long long unsigned i
nt ..._Indexes1 = {_Indexes1 ...}; _Args2 = {_Args2 ...}; long long unsigned int ..._Indexes2 = {_Indexes2 ...}; _T1 = const std::__cx
x11::basic_string<char>; _T2 = engine::Scene*]'
  335 |         pair(tuple<_Args1...>&, tuple<_Args2...>&,
      |         ^~~~
C:/terminal/mingw64/include/c++/14.1.0/bits/stl_pair.h:335:9: note:   candidate expects 4 arguments, 2 provided
C:/terminal/mingw64/include/c++/14.1.0/bits/stl_pair.h:299:9: note: candidate: 'template<class ... _Args1, class ... _Args2> constexpr
 std::pair<_T1, _T2>::pair(std::piecewise_construct_t, std::tuple<_Args1 ...>, std::tuple<_Args2 ...>) [with _Args1 = {_Args1 ...}; _A
rgs2 = {_Args2 ...}; _T1 = const std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>; _T2 = engine::Scene*]'
  299 |         pair(piecewise_construct_t, tuple<_Args1...>, tuple<_Args2...>);
      |         ^~~~
C:/terminal/mingw64/include/c++/14.1.0/bits/stl_pair.h:299:9: note:   candidate expects 3 arguments, 2 provided
C:/terminal/mingw64/include/c++/14.1.0/bits/stl_pair.h:346:7: note: candidate: 'constexpr std::pair<_T1, _T2>::pair() requires (is_def
ault_constructible_v<_T1>) && (is_default_constructible_v<_T2>) [with _T1 = const std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>; _T2 = engine::Scen
e*]'
  346 |       pair()
      |       ^~~~
C:/terminal/mingw64/include/c++/14.1.0/bits/stl_pair.h:346:7: note:   candidate expects 0 arguments, 2 provided
C:/terminal/mingw64/include/c++/14.1.0/bits/stl_pair.h:295:17: note: candidate: 'constexpr std::pair<_T1, _T2>::pair(std::pair<_T1, _T
2>&&) [with _T1 = const std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>; _T2 = engine::Scene*]'
  295 |       constexpr pair(pair&&) = default;         ///< Move constructor
      |                 ^~~~
C:/terminal/mingw64/include/c++/14.1.0/bits/stl_pair.h:295:17: note:   candidate expects 1 argument, 2 provided
C:/terminal/mingw64/include/c++/14.1.0/bits/stl_pair.h:294:17: note: candidate: 'constexpr std::pair<_T1, _T2>::pair(const std::pair<_
T1, _T2>&) [with _T1 = const std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>; _T2 = engine::Scene*]'
  294 |       constexpr pair(const pair&) = default;    ///< Copy constructor
      |                 ^~~~
C:/terminal/mingw64/include/c++/14.1.0/bits/stl_pair.h:294:17: note:   candidate expects 1 argument, 2 provided
ninja: build stopped: subcommand failed.

提示コード
SceneManagerクラス
#ifndef SCEMANAGER_HPP___
#define SCEMANAGER_HPP___

#include <unordered_map>
#include <string>
#include "engine/Scene.hpp"

namespace engine
{
    class Scene;

    class SceneManager
    {
    
    public:
        static void Add(const char* name,const Scene *scene)
        {
            sceneList.emplace(std::string(name),scene);
        }

        static void Load(const char* name)
        {
            sceneList[std::string(name)]->Start(); 
        }

        static void Switch(const char* name)
        {
            currentScene = (Scene*)sceneList[name];
        }

        static void Loop()
        {
            currentScene->Loop();
        }

//        static void Unload();


    private:

        SceneManager() = default;
        ~SceneManager() = default;

        static Scene* currentScene;
        static std::unordered_map<std::string,Scene*> sceneList;

    };
}

#endif

#include "engine/SceneManager.hpp"



namespace engine
{
    Scene* SceneManager::currentScene = nullptr;
    std::unordered_map<std::string,Scene*> SceneManager::sceneList; 
}

Sceneクラス
#ifndef ___SCENE_HPP___
#define ___SCENE_HPP___

#include <vector>

namespace engine
{
    class GameObject;
    class Scene
    {
    public:
        Scene() = default;
        ~Scene() = default;

        virtual void Start() = 0;

        void Loop();

       void Destroy();


    private:

        void Update();
        void Render();
 
    std::vector<GameObject*> gameObjectList;


    };
}

#endif


最重要の最初のエラーメッセージが欠落していると思います。note: candidate 以降の行は不要です。
エラーは const が付いているときのものですか? どこに const を付けるのですか? const なしではどうなったのでしょうか。

「std::unordered_mapstd::string,Scene*」の「Scene*」にconstが付いてないのに、const付きの値を入れようとしてエラーが出てるのだと思うけど、「constを外して実装を試した」というのが意味不明。

「キーと値の値を変更不可」これは、unordered_mapのエントリを一度登録すると値の書き換えできなくしたい、ということですかね。

はいそうです。値は変わりませんが、そのScene型の値が指すアドレスの先のデータは書き換えるようにしたいです。

エラーが更新されましたが、「中略」のところにあるはずのものがメインのエラーメッセージです。

コンパイルエラーになるのは、コメントに書いた通りSceneManager::Add()でconst Scene *をScene *に変換できないからです。


constを使ってキーと値の値を変更不可し、値が持つアドレスの指す先は変更できるようしたい。

上記の行いたい事は、std::unordered_map<std::string,Scene*> sceneListと変数定義した上で普通にstd::unordered_map::emplace()するだけで実現できているはずですが、何ができないのでしょうか？
https://cpprefjp.github.io/reference/unordered_map/unordered_map/emplace.html

効果
std::forward(args)... から構築された value_type のオブジェクトを t とすると、t.first と等価なキーがコンテナに既に存在していなければ、t をコンテナに挿入する。

エラーにしたいなら、emplaceする前にcontainsでキーが登録済みかを調べる、
static void Add(const char* name, Scene *scene)
{
    if ( sceneList.contains(name) ) throw std::invalid_argument("XXX");
    sceneList.emplace(name, scene);
}

コードの見た目上分かり易く黙って無視して良いなら、emplaceの代わりにtry_emplaceを使えば良いのではないでしょうか。
static void Add(const char* name, Scene *scene)
{
    sceneList.try_emplace(name, scene);
}

